# Can't subscribe to any YouTube channels - Why?

Tags: youtube

I've attempted to subscribe to several YouTube channels and it never works. I get the following:

**Google Accounts
We are sorry, but you do not have access to this service. Please contact your domain administrator for access.**

I am the domain administrator. I've checked all the setting and can't locate what could be stopping the subscription. Eventually, I want to get my own channel and write code to get at subscription data, but I can't even seem to get through the front door as a user. What am I missing?

Comment: This happened to me a while back, the problem just "vanished" after a couple of days though. Check some online articles regarding the problem, if you've not done so already. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/K8C9AF7zVZM

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, the "Best Answer" solution provides me with the same message when I go to ttp://www.youtube.com/address_book. This has been going on for over a year and it's now gotten to the point where I finally started looking for why this is happening. I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that I'm on the island of Roatan in the Caribbean.